# Webservice call before Fragment replacing with bottomview

Tags: android, web-services, android-fragments, android-activity

I want to call web service before my **`Fragment1`** initialize.  But In `MainActivity` first my `Fragment1` Replacing then my webservice call occurs.  Now how to handle that ? I am using `Retrofit` for web service calling.
I can not call Webservice in Fragment 1. Because i dont want to repeat during fragment  initialization.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView findViewById(R.id.navigation);

//Here My webservice call which response value sent to Fragment 1 

bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
    (new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        }

        android.app.Fragment selectedFragment = null;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_item1:
                selectedFragment = Fragment1.newInstance();
                toolbar.setTitle("1");
                break;
            case R.id.action_item2:
                selectedFragment = Fragment2.newInstance();
                toolbar.setTitle("2");
                break;

            default:
                selectedFragment = Fragment1.newInstance();
                toolbar.setTitle("1");
                break;

        }
        android.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, selectedFragment);
        transaction.commit();
        return true;
        }
    });


android.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, Fragment1.newInstance());
transaction.commit();
    } 
}
```

Comment: by default 1st fragment is loaded in the parent activity so you have to fetch value before sending intent to MainActivity

Comment: This is a last option for me but Is their any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: In that way the activity will be blank & This is the behaviour of the activity when loaded with fragments you have to show. **Best way to do that is use a Async Task & update the UI after getting response from the server to the fragment.**

Comment: I am replacing my first fragment (default fragment) in web service call response  (Temp. Solution  working) . Thanks for your suggestion.